# Rails--Build a filter on top of geocoder search

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm currently using geocoder to filter images, On top of that, I want to add a category filter(not the dropdown select type, but each category gets displayed like a button and when I click it, its category_id get selected).

So imagine a side bar that lists out all my categories and a location search input box.

This is what I have so far.

```html
#index.html.erb

<%= form_tag images_path, :method => :get do %>
  <p> Location<br>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <% submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <%= link_to cat.name %> #then i don't know what to do to get the cat.id link back to the controller
<% end %>

<% @images.each do |image| %> 
  <%= image_tag image.picture.url %>  
<% end %>

I have the location filter form and below that, it lists out the appropriate images.
```

```html
# imagescontroller

def index
    #@categories = Category.all
    if params[:search].present?
      @users = User.near(params[:search], 50, :select => "users.*, images.*").joins(:images)
      @images = Image.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: 3 }).joins(:users).merge(@users).distinct
    else
      @images = Image.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: 3 }) 
    end
 end
```

As you can see the code above, I hardcoded the category to the third category, but the code does run successfully when i input a location.

Background story:

- Each image can have many users, each user can have many images.
- Each user has an address, and I use geocoder to find images that has users who are near a certain location.
- Each image has many categories and each category has many images.
- There are only five categories

Now the question is: how can I make the category form so that users can choose the category, rather than me hardcoding it. I want the page to load without refreshing the page. And I have very little knowledge on jQuery and Ajax, but I'm willing to look more into it, I do need some direction tho.

Any solutions, suggestions or guidance are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
I can link the view like this

```html
<li><%= link_to "categoryname1", images_path(category: 'category name", search: params[:search]) %> </li>
```

the key is to also add the search params in the list as well

in the image controller, i edited the code. 
I use if else statement in the controller to get different results based on different situations (i.e. if the search and category params are both present...)

```html
    category = Category.where('lower(name) = ?', params[:category].downcase).first
    category_id = category.id unless category.nil?
    @images = Image.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: category_id })
```